# Angular - How to access JSON response defined and saved in other class?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I have a component which is using a service `login.service.ts` for http Call. The http call is retrieving data from DB.

I also use `MatTableModule` for the view based on the following [example](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/material-examples/table-basic/table-basic-example.ts). But I want to retrieve and display my own data dynamically from the response and not from the hard coded dataSource as in the example.

**`users.component.ts`**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
import { LoginService, UserService} from '../../_service';
import { CustomMaterialModule } from '../../custom-material/custom-material.module';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-users',
    templateUrl: './users.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})

export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private loginService:LoginService, public http: Http) {}

    displayedColumns = ['ID', 'email', 'name'];
    dataSource = new ExampleDataSource();

    errorMessage:any;
    userData: {};

    ngOnInit() { this.retrieveUsers(); }

    retrieveUsers() {
        this.loginService.getUsersList()
        .subscribe(
            (res) => {
                console.log('Get ID: ' + JSON.stringify(res.message[0]._id) );
                this.userData = res.message;
            },(err) => {
                this.errorMessage = err;
            }
        )
    }
}


let test:Object = {
    "error": false,
    "message": [
        {
          "_id": "59415f148911240fc812d393",
          "email": "jane.doe@foo.de",
          "fullName": "Jane Doe",
          "__v": 0,
          "created": "2017-06-14T16:06:44.457Z"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5943b80be8b8b605686a67fb",
          "email": "john.doe@foo.de",
          "fullName": "John Doe",
          "__v": 0,
          "created": "2017-06-16T10:50:51.180Z"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5952476be50d780ab2aa1f88",
          "email": "donovan@foo.de",
          "fullName": "Steve donovan",
          "__v": 0,
          "created": "2017-06-27T11:54:19.879Z"
        },
        {
          "_id": "595247f8e50d780ab2aa1f89",
          "email": "donald@foo.de",
          "fullName": "Donald Duck",
          "__v": 0,
          "created": "2017-06-27T11:56:40.666Z"
        }
    ]
}

export interface Element {
    _id: number;
    email: string;
    fullName: string;
}

const data: Element[] = [
    { _id: test['message'][0]._id, email: test['message'][0].email, fullName: test['message'][0].fullName},
    { _id: test['message'][1]._id, email: test['message'][1].email, fullName: test['message'][1].fullName},
    { _id: test['message'][2]._id, email: test['message'][2].email, fullName: test['message'][2].fullName}
];

export class ExampleDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
    /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
    connect(): Observable<Element[]> {
        return Observable.of(data);
    }

    disconnect() {}
}
```

The issue is that I can't access the variable: `userData` within the class component: `UsersComponent` in order to pass it to `data` in class `ExampleDataSource` from type `Element` (interface).

I tried to create an instance of `UsersComponent` class and use it in the rest of the code, but it didn't work.

The hard coded JSON object in the code is just for testing propose if order to check if it otherwise works. With hard coded JSON, all the data is being passed to the view/html `users.component.html` and looks clean.

**`users.component.html`**:

```
  <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

        <!-- Position Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element._id}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Email </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.email}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Weight Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.fullName}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
</div>
```

Here is one of my tries to pass the data dynamically which didn't work of course:

```
const data: Element[] = [
    { _id: this.userData[0]._id, email: this.userData[0].email, fullName: this.userData[0].fullName},
    { _id: this.userData[1]._id, email: this.userData[1].email, fullName: this.userData[1].fullName},
    { _id: this.userData[2]._id, email: this.userData[2].email, fullName: this.userData[2].fullName},
];
```

How can I get around this to pass the JSON from response which is saved in the variable `this.userData` in class `UsersComponent`?

Comment: You might want to follow [`table-http-example.ts`](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/material-examples/table-http/table-http-example.ts) instead of the basic example. I would move `retrieveUsers()` into your implementation of `DataSource`.

Comment: Good idea... I'll give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Also the example `table-http` is using pagination and sorting etc. which causes other bugs/errors at that stage where I don't have that much time to make changes in all the different files I'am using such `login.service.ts` etc. Any other hint please?

Comment: @tony19: FYI - I followed this example on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mjQbufh7cUynD6qhF5Ap?p=preview). Looks in a way simple and maintainable. It's also making a `Http` call and passing the data to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

**`users.component.ts`**:

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
    displayedColumns = ['ID', 'Email', 'Name'];
    exampleDatabase: RetrieveUsrData | null;
    dataSource: UsrDataSource | null;
    constructor(http: Http) {
      this.exampleDatabase = new RetrieveUsrData(http);
      this.dataSource = new UsrDataSource(this.exampleDatabase);
    }
    ngOnInit(){}
}

export interface UsersData {
  ID: number;
  Email: string;
  Name: string;
}
export class RetrieveUsrData {
    private issuesUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/users';
    getRepoIssues(): Observable<UsersData[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.issuesUrl)
                        .map(this.extractData)
    }
    extractData(result: Response): UsersData[] {
        return result.json().message.map(issue => {
            return {
                ID: issue._id,
                Email: issue.email,
                Name: issue.fullName,
            }
        });
    }
    constructor(private http: Http) {}
}
export class UsrDataSource extends DataSource<UsersData> {
  constructor(private _exampleDatabase: RetrieveUsrData) {
    super();
  }
  connect(): Observable<UsersData[]> {
    return this._exampleDatabase.getRepoIssues();
  }
  disconnect() {}
}
```